# Using /usr/local/bin/mpd instead of /usr/bin/mpd

Tags: systemd, mpd

I want to run a patched mpd installed in /usr/local/bin. Usually it's started by:
`sudo service mpd start`.

Changing the:
`DAEMON=/usr/bin/mpd`
to
`DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/mpd`
in /etc/init.d/mpd has no effect: service still starts /usr/bin/mpd.

I noticed a /lib/systemd/system/mpd.service file and try to change its

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/mpd --no-daemon $MPDCONF`
to
`ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/mpd --no-daemon $MPDCONF`

but now the mpd service won't start.

Here is the output from systemctl status mpd

```
● mpd.service - Music Player Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since jeu. 2016-04-21 11:04:26 CEST; 2s ago
  Process: 26778 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/mpd --no-daemon $MPDCONF (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 26778 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

avril 21 11:04:25 lago systemd[1]: Started Music Player Daemon.
avril 21 11:04:26 lago mpd[26778]: cmdline: No configuration file found
avril 21 11:04:26 lago systemd[1]: mpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
avril 21 11:04:26 lago systemd[1]: mpd.service: Unit entered failed state.
avril 21 11:04:26 lago systemd[1]: mpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
avril 21 11:04:26 lago systemd[1]: mpd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
avril 21 11:04:26 lago systemd[1]: Failed to start Music Player Daemon.
avril 21 11:04:26 lago systemd[1]: mpd.service: Failed with result 'start-limit'.
```

I check that:
`sudo /usr/local/bin/mpd --no-daemon /etc/mpd.conf`
works from command line.

I'm lost in this service configuration. What should I modify?

Comment: What does `systemctl status mpd` say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that changing `$MPDCONF` to `/etc/mpd.conf` fixed the problem. What is weird is that this line was working fine with `/usr/bin/mpd`